# Android Billing Currency giving Locale Price

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, currency

I am doing multiplatform app (web, iOS, android). My app start the work global, so i have to keep currency and price, when user buy a item. My target countries prices are not converted automatically. Android billing method gives default currency. I did not find a solution for it?

Here is my code

```
Bundle querySku = new Bundle();
        querySku.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);
        try {
            Bundle skuDetails = mIabHelper.getService().getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(), "subs", querySku);
            int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
            if (response == 0) {
                ArrayList<String> responseList = skuDetails.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");
                String responseJson = responseList.get(0);
                JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(responseJson);
                currencyType = responseObject.getString("price_currency_code");
                price = responseObject.getDouble("price_amount_micros");
```

this code gives me always my sku default price.

For example If i buy this item with turkish currency return Turkish(TRY), if i buy with euros currency return turkish(TRY). But in bill user see euro.

Anyone has suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

i think google lab service was change and now they did not announce anything.